# Proving if a relation is or is not transitive.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let S be a set that contains at least two different elements. Let R be the
relation on $P(S)$, the set of all subsets of S, defined by $(X, Y ) \in R$ if and only if
$X \cap Y = \emptyset$.

I am trying to prove if this is transitive or not.  I from what I am understanding about transitivity I don't think it is.

Here is my answer right now:

$R$ is **not transitive** because if $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{3,4\}$ and $Z=\{2, 6\}$ then $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ and $Y\cap Z = \emptyset$ but $X \cap Z = \{2\}$.

I am not sure if this works as a counter example.

Comment: That's a fine counterexample. You just need one case where $aRb$ and $bRc$ but where it is not true that $aRc$.

Comment: You could just pick non-empty $X=Z$ and $Y=\emptyset$. Always best to go with the "most trivial" counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a very simple counterexample using the facts that the relation is symmetric, there are some $X,Y$ such that $X R Y$, and for all $X\ne \emptyset$, not $XRX$. All that's required is for $S\ne \emptyset$, it doesn't need to have two or more elements. Any subset of $S$ bears $R$ to $\emptyset\subseteq S$, in particular $S$ itself does, and vice versa:
$$\begin{align}
S R \emptyset &\quad\text{because $S\cap \emptyset = \emptyset$, and} \\
\emptyset R S &\quad\text{for the same reason};
\end{align}$$ 
However, it's not the case that $S R S$, as $S = S\cap S$ is nonempty.

---

Your counterexample works, but you should come up with a similar proof using just the data you're given — a set with $\ge 2$ elements (yours has at least $6$).

Perhaps the question(er) meant to disqualify the empty set from the range of the relation. In that case, it *is* essential to have at least two elements in $S$. Say $a,b\in S$, $a\ne b$. Let $X=Z = \{a\}, Y=\{b\}$. Then $X R Y$ and $Y R Z$, but not $X R Z$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that works, the idea being that just because $X,Y$ are disjoint, and $Y,Z$ are disjoint does not always imply that $X,Z$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but introduce extra entities.   You have used six specific elements.

$S$ is given as a set with *at least* 2 elements.   Any counter example we use to prove a *general* result about $S$ should come from the *smallest* case.

That is: don't use more than two elements; and don't use any particular elements.   Be generic.

---

We know $S$ contains at least two distinct elements.   Let us label them $a, b$.   As such, $\mathcal P(S)=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\ldots,S\}$

Now $\{a\}\cap \{b\}=\emptyset$ and $\{b\}\cap \{a\}=\emptyset$ but $\{a\}\cap \{a\}\neq \emptyset$.   So the relation on *any* such $S$ is not transitive.